# Putting images side by side On Doxygen

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard, doxygen-addtogroup

I am trying to put several images on my main page of the Doxygen file but had no luck finding an answer online, 
Doxygen puts the two pictures on top of each other.

Is there any way to make it side by side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default doxygen places images in separate paragraphs. There are some possibilities:

- embed the images in a table(row)
- embed the images in some native    output code, so in \htmlonly ...
  \endhtmlony or \latexonly    ...\endlatexonly blocks.